# Java Panel font changing radio buttons question

Tags: java, fonts, radio-button

I am having trouble with this assignment because my of my actionlisteners.  Right now the panel has 2 checkboxes to change the font into bold and or italic.  I want to add 4 radio buttons that can change what font the "saying" is in.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my actionlisteners? Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StyleOptionsPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
private JLabel saying;
private JCheckBox bold, italic; // have a button for style1, button for style2, button for style3
private JRadioButton style1, style2, style3, style4; //creates the buttons for each of the 4 styles
{
    bold = new JCheckBox ("Bold", true);
    italic = new JCheckBox ("Italic", true);

    style1 = new JRadioButton ("Arial", true);
    style2 = new JRadioButton ("Times New Roman", false);
    style3 = new JRadioButton ("Verdana", false);
    style4 = new JRadioButton ("Thonburi", false);

    //also check out quote options panel file for example of radio buttons.
    //after creating your radio buttons, you have to create a button group. copy line exactly from quote options panel
    //comedy = new JRadioButton ("Comedy", true); - example of assigning radio button
    //comedy.setBackground (Color.green);
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup(); //use this code for the homework
    group.add (style1);
    group.add (style2);
    group.add (style3);
    group.add (style4);

    style1.addActionListener (this);
    style2.addActionListener (this);
    style3.addActionListener (this);
    style4.addActionListener (this);

    add (style1);
    add (style2);
    add (style3);
    add (style4);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Sets up a panel with a label and some check boxes that
//  control the style of the label's font.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public StyleOptionsPanel()
{
    saying = new JLabel ("Say it with style!");
    saying.setFont (new Font ("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 36)); // we'll need this later

    bold = new JCheckBox ("Bold"); // what is in quotes doesn't have to match variable being created but it should be descriptive
    bold.setBackground (Color.green); // you can also set the background color of the checkbox
    italic = new JCheckBox ("Italic");
    italic.setBackground (Color.green); // this doesn't seem to change anything for me?

    //StyleListener listener = new StyleListener(); //whenever you create a textbox, you have to add a listener for it
    //bold.addActionListener (listener);
    //italic.addActionListener (listener);

    add (saying); //it matters what order these go in, it affects the way that your program looks
    add (bold);
    add (italic);
    add (style1);
    add (style2);
    add (style3);
    add (style4);

    setBackground (Color.cyan);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 100));
}

//*****************************************************************
//  Represents the listener for both check boxes and the radio boxes.
//*****************************************************************
private class StyleListener implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Updates the style of the label font style.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        int style = Font.PLAIN;

        if (bold.isSelected()) //this is a boolean statement, on the inside you will always expect some kind of boolean statement
            style = Font.BOLD;

        if (italic.isSelected())
            style += Font.ITALIC; // style += means that it takes whatever style the font already is and then adds the value Italic to it
        //public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) //also use this code in homework

        Object source = e.getSource();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // this is our bread and butter, it is basically what we will be changing
    {


        if (source == style1) //if (source == style1)
            saying.setText (Arial); //quote.setText(Helvetica)
        else (source == style2)
        saying.setText (TimesNewRoman);
        else (source == style3)
        saying.setText (Verdana);
        else (source == style4)
        saying.setText(Thonburi);
    }

}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous answer, your are adding the wrong ActionListener.

```
StyleListener styleListener = new StyleListener();
style1.addActionListener(styleListener);
style2.addActionListener(styleListener);
style3.addActionListener(styleListener);
style4.addActionListener(styleListener);
```

and you should also do the same for the checkboxes

```
bold.addItemListener(styleListener);
italic.addItemListener(styleListener);
```

Your main StyleOptionsPanel need not to be be a listener.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding this as an ActionListener to your radio buttons, yet listener methods are implemented in a separate StyleListener class.